# Tailwind CSS plugins are not applying to Angular components

Tags: angular, tailwind-css

I'm using Tailwind CSS in my Angular 16 project (tried in Angular 13 too), i had installed using Angular installation tutorial, all CSS features are working, except for the plugins like @tailwindcss/forms.

I ran the following commands to install Tailwind:

```
npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
npx tailwindcss init
npm install -D @tailwindcss/forms
```

Configured my `tailwind.config.js`:

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
    content: [
        "./src/**/*.{html,ts}",
        "./src/index.html"
    ],
    theme: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [
        require("@tailwindcss/forms")({
            strategy: "class",
        }),
        require('prettier-plugin-tailwindcss'),
        require('flowbite/plugin')
    ],
};
```

Added tailwind to my `styles.css`:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

My folder structure is:

```
.
└── MyApp/
    ├── node_modules
    ├── src/
    │   ├── app/
    │   │   ├── other-modules/
    │   │   │   └── ...
    │   │   ├── app.module.ts
    │   │   ├── app.component.ts
    │   │   ├── app.component.html
    │   │   └── ...
    │   ├── index.html
    │   ├── styles.css
    │   └── ...
    ├── tailwind.config.js
    └── ...
```

And in my app.component.html i used the `form-input` class:

```html
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-input" placeholder="Enter your email">
```

Can someone help me with this problem, none of my installed plugins seems the CSS working.

Edit: My package.json

```
{
    "name": "web-angular",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
        "test": "ng test"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^16.0.0",
        "@angular/common": "^16.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "^16.0.0",
        "@angular/core": "^16.0.0",
        "@angular/forms": "^16.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.0.0",
        "@angular/router": "^16.0.0",
        "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.13.0",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.4.0",
        "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.4.0",
        "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.4.0",
        "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.4.0",
        "flowbite": "^1.6.5",
        "flowbite-angular": "^0.0.1",
        "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
        "tslib": "^2.3.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.0.0",
        "@angular/cli": "~16.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.0.0",
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.3",
        "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
        "jasmine-core": "~4.6.0",
        "karma": "~6.4.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
        "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
        "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
        "postcss": "^8.4.23",
        "postcss-import": "^15.1.0",
        "prettier": "^2.8.8",
        "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.2.8",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2",
        "typescript": "~5.0.2"
    },
    "description": "This project was generated with [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) version 16.0.0.",
    "main": "tailwind.config.js",
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use some more complex [components from flowbite](https://flowbite.com/blocks/) to see if it's working? It's not really visible on the `form-input`. Is something in devtools?

Comment: @joka00 same for flowbite, i can import the component but the css isn't applied. And devtools has no errors.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce it, could you update the question with your `package.json` or at least the versions of the involved packages?

Comment: @joka00 i've updated the post with my `package.json`

Comment: Is it a standalone project? I am having issues when using angular in standalone mode

Comment: @Spock yes, standalone project!

Comment: @JoãoPedro I made an issue on Angular github, turned out if you use esbuild then it did not work. Yesterday 16.1.1 was released with support for it.  So if you use esbuild that will solve it for you.

Answer (score 0):

The new ESbuild based builder did not have support for Tailwind inside SCSS files.

With Angular 16.1 this has now been implemented, and should resolve the issue.

Comment: I've updated Angular to 16.1, and Tailwind plugins like prettier-plugin-tailwindcss still not working

Comment: Are you sure? They do for me and they specifically answered my issue here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/25362 Maybe it's a different issue. My issue was that @apply and tailwind classes applied in .scss files in components, did not work. But they do now. Are you using ESBuild?

Comment: @JoãoPedro I just checked, and those plugins work for me, I am using Angular 16.1.2, ESBuild, Standalone app. I use pNPM but that should not matter to you.